chcp command changes the piping behavior
There is a script cat.bat emulating unix cat: it reads from input stream and then write into output stream:
@echo off
for /f "tolens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr  /n "^"') do (
  echo(%%b)
)

I can use it in two manners with the same result:
type textfile | cat.bat
cat.bat < textfile

If I insert line chcp>nul before for loop then only the first form (with |) works. The second one (using <) outputs nothing.
Why could this be? And how to achieve unified behavior?

It should be tokens, not tolens, and echo(%%b not echo(%%b).

I assume you realize that the far more efficient way to do that is doskey cat=type %*.

@Compo Of course tokens and echo(%%b. It was a typo. Sorry

@TimRoberts But with this doskey macro, you cannot pipe or redirect to. But the question is all about piping and redirection

It's a strange behavior, I can't explain it, but I can circumvent it.
Using find instead of findstr solves the problem.
@echo off
chcp > NUL

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims="  %%a in ('find /n /v ""') do (
    set "line=%%a"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:*]=!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
)

I suppose the chcp simply flushes the input stream, but only when the input comes from a redirect.
But FIND has the special ability to reset a file redirection, each time it's called.
test.bat
@echo off
chcp

echo Read from stdin with findstr
findstr  /n "^"
echo(
echo Read from stdin with find
find /n /v ""

Test with: type text.txt | test.bat

Aktive Codepage: 850.
Read from stdin with findstr
1:Line1
2:Line2
Read from stdin with find

Test with: test.bat < text.txt

Aktive Codepage: 850.
Read from stdin with findstr
Read from stdin with find
[1]Line1
[2]Line2



I've forgotten to test find. It works. Thank you!
It seems yes, find somehow reset redirection. And if we add one more line find /n /v "" in the test.bat the second one again reads from stream and outputs the same results.
Offtop: if I replace the entire loop with one line for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""') do echo(%%b for simplicity is it something wrong with it?
What's a goal for chcp >con in test.bat?


@VladGGG The for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""') do echo(%%b has the drawback of removing leading ], if they are in the text.  3) I just forgot to remove chcp > con, I tested so much ...

Yes, when this ] (or mu4ltiply symbols ]) is at the begining of line
